# A Need To Check For Daylight Saving Time

Tags: php, date, datetime, time, save

What i am trying to archive is what time exactly a post was posted based on the users default timezone via there IP.

What i am worried about is daylight saving time so say if it's 1:46PM now then if daylight saving time in effect it might still post a update as 1:46PM instead of the exact time 3:46PM

The question is does PHP automatically check against that? or is there anything I need to do to see if daylight saving is in effect or not

```
$timezone = '+0:00';
$timezone = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $timezone) * 36;
$timezone_name = timezone_name_from_abbr(null, $timezone, true);
date_default_timezone_set($timezone_name);
echo date('D d M Y H:i:s');
```

Thanks :)

Just checking as everything needs to be 100% accurate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes, PHP can give you the precise time based on timezone, regardless of DST. For example, if a user's IP tells you that they're in New York, you could do

```
$date = date_create('now America/New_York');
```

to create a [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object with the current time in New York.

```
echo $date->format('h:i:s');
```

Incidentally, DST is currently in effect, and this code prints the correct current time of 12:21:32.

---

**EDIT**

In response to your follow-up question, yes, the time that you save is the time that you will retrieve. For example,

```
$timestamp = (int) $date->format('U');
```

would save the absolute unix time of 12:21:32 (or whenever you run this code), regardless of timezone or DST. Another DateTime object will yield the same time:

```
$retrieved = new DateTime;
$retrieved->setTimestamp($timestamp);
echo $retrieved->format('h:i:s'); // outputs '12:21:32'
```

Hope that helps.

**EDIT 2**

To answer your next question, it is indeed possible to adjust a DateTime you've saved to a different timezone. First, set your script's default timezone to UTC.

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
```

Then, you can save your timestamps as shown above (except, don't specify a timezone), and when you retrieve them, you can adjust them to where your users are:

```
echo $retrieved->format('h:i:s'); // Outputs UTC time of 5:21:32
$retrieved->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
echo $retrieved->format('h:i:s'); // Outputs correct New York time of 12:21:32
```

Even after DST ends, this code would still display 12:21:32 (or, again, whatever time at which you run it)

Hope that helps, again!

---

**EDIT 3**

To address your most recent question, you can always just adjust the DateTime object based on the user's settings. For example, if they decide to override DST to off, then you should

```
// Change your default timezone to that of your user
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

// Check for daylight savings time with date('I')
if (date('I', $timestamp) == 1) $retrieved->modify('-1 hour');
```

And that should do it!

Comment: ok thanks :) so this will also be the same on date_default_timezone? also say if a post was posted when dst was not in effect (say10:17PM) will the post still display the same time when dst comes in effect?

Comment: this is most painfull thing i have ever had to do in php and thanks for your help so far

Comment: Thanks :) helps a bit more :) last question what I am doing is storing each post with the UTC timezone or australia/brisbane so based on where you live I want to get the time it was exactly posted without daylight saving time effecting anything so for example (10:17PM is the UTC time it was posted) then in the america offset time it displays 1PM i don't want daylight saving changing that time and vice versa.
hope is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: im starting to find it impossible to get each timezone to be accurate with all these conidtions maybe I should stick to just displaying the australian time it was posted

Comment: one last question even know I said that above lol I have a better solutions maybe I could have a option where the user can manually enable or disable daylight saving times and override the defaults, I think it be better and it adds more cusomibility to the feature i'm building
thanks loads ;)
i can promoise once you answer this my query is solved and I up vote/accept your answer

Comment: Thanks :D
this should do it!
think this be the most best solution

Comment: retrieved is  a undefined method

Comment: The code I posted works in my tests. How are you creating `$retrieved`? Calling `new DateTime` or `date_create()` should be the way.